# JAVA read csv file with scanner, didn't work

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

class Flight {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Flight x = new Flight();
        x.data();
    }

    public void data() throws Exception {

        File fn = new File("ChinaAirLine.csv");
        Scanner obj = new Scanner(fn);
        while (obj.hasNextLine()) {
            System.out.println(obj.nextLine());
        }
        obj.close();
    }
}
```

I use scanner to read the csv file, but it can't work, and there is no exception throw out

I want to know how to fix it, it really confuse me, when i read bds file, it work, but csv didn't!!!

Comment: Please don't post images of code, please copy the code and paste it directly into the question.

Comment: Can you add the actual code to your question?  Also, what is the specific error you're encountering.  Your code appears to be correct for reading lines of a file.

Comment: the command line didnt tell me what wrong with the code, it finish the compile, but not thing happen, it just finish with nothing

Comment: Is your ChinaAirline.csv empty?

Comment: And is the file right next to the `Flight.class` file? If it is not in the same folder, it may be grabbing the wrong ChinaAirline.csv

Comment: no, it have some thing in it, and the file is in the same folder

Comment: What is a ”bds file”?

Answer (score 0):

In modern Java, use the [NIO.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_I/O_(Java)) classes rather than the legacy file-system classes.

```
Path path = Paths.get("/Users/basil_dot_work/IdeaProjects/Ex20/src/main/java/work/basil/example/parsing/airlines.csv" );
```

Put some example data in that file. We store the name of an airline, and the year of its founding.

```
Air Canada,1937
Air France,1933
Air New Zealand,1940
```

You could verify the [file’s existence](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#exists(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.LinkOption...)).

```
boolean exists = Files.exists( path ) ;
```

Pass that path to the constructor of `Scanner`, along with an explicit character encoding.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner ( path , StandardCharsets.UTF_8 ) ;
```

A `Scanner` is a resource that should be closed when no longer needed. As a habit, use the [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax to automatically close. And catch any `IOException`.

Within our try-with-resources, parse the file.

Specify the delimiter. For our needs that means a newline, to parse each line.

```
scanner.useDelimiter ( "\n" );
```

For each line, split the string into our two parts.

```
String[] parts = line.split ( "," );
```

We use each part to instantiate an object our of our class `Airline` which we defined as a [record](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395).

```
record Airline( String name , Year founded ) { }
```

We add each new `Airline` object to a list. And finally dump that list to the console.

We loop the lines by leveraging the fact that a [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html) is an [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Iterator.html). An `Iterator` has a [`forEachRemaining`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Iterator.html#forEachRemaining(java.util.function.Consumer)) method to make the looping neat. We pass a lambda to handle each line. If you are not comfortable with lambdas yet, you can replace the `forEachRemaining` with a conventional loop.

### Entire example code

```java
package work.basil.example.parsing;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.time.Year;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AirlineParsing
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        Path path = Paths.get ( "/Users/basil_dot_work/IdeaProjects/Ex20/src/main/java/work/basil/example/parsing/airlines.csv" );
        try
                (
                        Scanner scanner = new Scanner ( path , StandardCharsets.UTF_8 ) ;
                )
        {
            scanner.useDelimiter ( "\n" );
            record Airline( String name , Year founded ) { }
            List < Airline > airlines = new ArrayList <> ( 3 );
            scanner.forEachRemaining ( ( String line ) ->
            {
                String[] parts = line.split ( "," );
                Airline airline = new Airline ( parts[ 0 ] , Year.parse ( parts[ 1 ] ) );
                airlines.add ( airline );
            } );
            System.out.println ( "airlines = " + airlines );
        }
        catch ( IOException e ) { throw new RuntimeException ( e ); }
    }
}
```

When run.

> airlines = [Airline[name=Air Canada, founded=1937], Airline[name=Air France, founded=1933], Airline[name=Air New Zealand, founded=1940]]

---

The above code is well and good as a learning exercise. But you should know that in real work we would use one of the multiple fine CSV parsing libraries available in the Java ecosystem. For example, [*Apache Commons CSV*](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/).

Comment: i have a question, is that a hashset method?

Comment: @黃祥瑋 No `Set` involved in this Answer.